# What does a period mean in a url?

Tags: url

I use a website that has a URL like....

```
https://wwws.something.com/overview.event
```

I have never seen a period used in a URL like this before.
I cannot find anything on google or stack overflow of anyone describing this

What does it mean? How is it used?

To clarify it is the "overview.event" that I am confused about

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. You could have an URI like `http://example.com/all.those.periods`

Comment: You've never seen a period before the extension before? How about `index.html` or `picture.jpg`?

Comment: Is it just the third period that has you flummoxed, or are they all a huge mystery to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Times where url was a path to file on server are gone. Now HTTP servers use rewriting (like mod_rewrite in Apache) to map url's to files with proper parameters.

Old PHP sites had url's like `www.myblog.com/page.php?page=1` where `page.php` was actual file and `?page=1` was GET argument that was used by PHP interpreter.

Some people decided that pages looks nicer and are more readable if we do something like `www.myblog.com/page/1` but there is no problem to do `www.myblog.com/page.1` as well.

Comment: I understand that you are saying "www.myblog.com/page/1" is the same as "www.myblog.com/page.1" however could you then explain why is it that when I go to www.myblog.com/page/1  my page loads, and when I go to www.myblog.com/page.1  the page does not load and I get an html error?

Comment: It can be same but only with proper configuration.  Most common frameworks use "/"  as separator but you can configure your Web server to rewrite "." as "/". Please google "mod_rewrite"

Answer (score 0):

The URL just means that we want to mean it !

See informations on wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator

You can have URL like http://www.example.com/image.**jpg** and have an gif image or a simple page or a video...

Comment: I understand that but overview.event is not a file

Comment: @Konrad: how do you know `overview.event` is not a file?

Comment: Calling a URL implies a server-side processing. Whether to "overview.event" or "toto" or "XXX" have no importance, the server answer can be the same.

But if no a good idea, the server answer can to be totally different the meaning of URL...

Comment: @Jongware -  If it was a file, I am confused as to how the web browser would be able to interpret it? I understand that /image.jpg loads because the web browser knows how to handle an image and display it or load index.html because the browser knows how to handle an html file or a php file, ect. But how could the browser know how to handle a file extension it doesn't recognize?

Comment: @Konrad: that would be indicated by its mime type.